# How to convert an image from CV_8UC1 to CV_32FC1 type in opencv?

Tags: opencv, image-processing

I readed an image which type of it is CV_8UC1, and I want to convert it to CV_32FC1.but when I use convertTO() function my image become completely white and I don't know why!

```
Mat Image(512,512,CV_32FC1);     
Image = imread("C:\\MGC.jpg",CV_LOAD_IMAGE_GRAYSCALE);   

/// show image
namedWindow("pic");
int x = 0; int y = 0;
imshow("pic", Image);

cout<<Image.type()<<endl;
Image.convertTo(Image,CV_32FC1);
cout<<Image.type()<<endl;

////show converted image 
namedWindow("pic1");
imshow("pic1",Image );
```

Comment: btw, your initial Image(512,512,CV_32FC1);  alloction will just get overwritten by inread. just leave it empty.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Because displayable range for 32FC type element images is [0:1] (for imshow).
Try this.

```
Image.convertTo(Image,CV_32FC1, 1.0/255.0);
```

Comment: Smorodov :   thank you for your response.It worked correctly.I have another question.If I change some pixels how can I convert it to CV_8UC1 type again?
I used Image.convertTo(Image,CV_8UC1) but it turned to completely black.

Comment: Image.convertTo(Image,CV_8UC1, 255.0);

Comment: which module has to be imported in order for this conversion?

Answer (score 0):

The methods used by Andrey do not seem to exist in current (v3.4) opencv for python.
Here is an alternative solution that uses scikit-image

http://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/user_guide/data_types.html

```
 import cv2
 from skimage import img_as_float

 cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

 ret, frame = cap.read()

 image1  = cv2.cvtColor(frame,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

 image2 = img_as_float(image1)

 cv2.imshow('IMAGE1',image1)
 cv2.imshow('IMAGE2', image2)

 while(1):
     k = cv2.waitKey(100) & 0xff
     if k == 27:
        break

 cap.release()
 cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Answer (score 0):

It is a scaling problem. `cvtColor` is tricky in the ranges of the data type. Read this [here](https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/imgproc/doc/miscellaneous_transformations.html#void%20cvtColor(InputArray%20src,%20OutputArray%20dst,%20int%20code,%20int%20dstCn)).

If you change from `CV_8U` to`CV32F` and vs. the ranges does not scale by themselves, You must indicate the scaling measure.